# a way to validate form fields with same name attribute

Tags: php, yii

I have the following form.

```
<form method="post">
<input name="lang[bg]" value="foo"/>
<input name="lang[en]" value="bar"/>
<input name="lang[de]" value="baz"/>
<input type="submit" />
```

How can I validate fields and show the errors in this case?

Comment: You will need model rules validations - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/.

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can do this

```
<form method="post" name="form1">
<input name="lang[bg]" value="foo"/>
<input name="lang[en]" value="bar"/>
<input name="lang[de]" value="baz"/>
<input type="submit" onclick="check();" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function check(){
        var v1 = ($('input[name="lang[bg]"]').val());
        var v2 =  ($('input[name="lang[en]"]').val());
        var v3 = ($('input[name="lang[de]"]').val());
    // do stuff with v1 v2 v3
}
</script>
```

Comment: I apologize for that statement, but it comes from the server sidе (Yii validation)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<input name="lang[bg]" value="foo"/>
<input name="lang[en]" value="bar"/>
<input name="lang[de]" value="baz"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validate(form) {
   if(form["lang[bg]"].value == "" || form["lang[bg]"].value == null)
     return false;
   else return true;
}
```

The above JavaScript shows the validation for one input element. Simply re-use this to validate the other elements.